# Returning a substring using Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, substring

I'm playing around with Perl and trying to get a better understanding of its substring/regex functionality.

Say I have a string such as

[48:31.8] Sent: >33*1311875297587*eval*0*frame[0]*"A"<

and want to return 1311875297587.  It will always be in that format.  How would I do this using Perl?

Thanks

Comment: Describe how you identify the part of interest. String of digits at least 3 digits long? Start with 4th character following ">"? digits before "*eval"? etc...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that "[48:31.8]..." is in $string, then:

```
my ($number) = $string =~ /\*(\d+)\*eval\*/;
```

`$number` will be undefined if the string doesn't match, otherwise it will contain the digits between `"*"` and `"*eval*"`.

Comment: I'd `split` that input on `*` and parse it based on the substring number. Less of a hack, more robust.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($str =~ /\*(\d+)\*/ ) {
    print $1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my ($num) = '>33*1311875297587*eval*0*frame[0]*"A"<' =~ /(\d{3,})/;
print $num;
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I think this is a more robust answer:

```
while(<STDIN>)
{
    @fields = split(/\*/,$1) if(/(?<=>)([^<>])+(?><)/);
    print "$fields[1]\n";
}
```

This allows access to all of your fields if you need them, and doesn't rely on inherent order to parse out a particular field.

Replace the `while` loop with whatever line-by-line iteration you want. For testing though, run this as a Perl script, then paste in your line `[48:31.8] Sent: >33*1311875297587*eval*0*frame[0]*"A"<` or whatever else.